# In Chrome, JS bound functions have null arguments.callee.caller

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, arguments, v8, ecmascript-5

From Chrome 17 on, arguments.callee.caller seems to be null for bound functions:

```
function a() {
  this.test = function() { console.debug('*** ' + arguments.callee.caller); };
  this.test();  // This prints the function
  this.bound = this.test.bind(this);
  this.bound(); // This prints null
}
```

The bound and unbound functions used to act consistently, but not anymore.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Would you mind filing a bug at http://new.crbug.com/ and posting the ID here? I'm not actually convinced that this result is incorrect, but it might be an inadvertent result of changing the bindings between WebCore and V8.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's not an error. You may note this: 
`If the function f was invoked by the top level code, the value of f.caller is null, otherwise it's the function that called f.` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Caller)

And when you use this in function a, `'this'` means `DOMWindow`. so When you bind bound function to `this`, bound function was invoked by the top level code. It returns `null`.

May it helps. rdtriny.

Answer (score 1):

`arguments.callee` and company are deprecated. They throw errors in strict mode. My guess is that they are being phased out in newer versions of Chrome. I can't confirm, though, because I'm still on 16.